# Facing export issue after upgrade site from Kentico 8.2 to Kentico 9

Tags: kentico

I have upgraded Kentico site from Kentico 8.2 to Kentico 9.0, everything was looking pretty and working smoothly. But when I tried to export my own site, I got Exception with following statement.

“Conversion failed when converting from a character string to unique identifier”.

Comment: Could you please provide us upgrade log (inetpub/wwwroot/yourinstance/log,txt)?

Answer (score 0):

From your current description it is impossible to tell what might have broken. The exception you are getting is very common and you can find many examples of reason why it happens here in SO.

However, what might be related to your question in Kentico is whether the upgrade you performed was successful. Try checking **CMS_SettingsKey** table for following **KeyNames**

> CMSDBVersion
>
> CMSDataVersion

Are they both set to 9.0? If not, the upgrade was not entirely successful. If yes, then there is some other issue within the data in your database for which we would need much more information.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the class form definitions haven't been upgraded properly. Try the upgrade again and make sure you perform all the [Steps after upgrade](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K9/Upgrading+to+Kentico+9#UpgradingtoKentico9-Stepsafterperformingtheupgrade), especially "**Running the website - First request**".